# Adding a widget with a button - wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm trying to create something like the categories panel in Wordpress, with wxPython.

What I'm trying to figure out, is how to add a widget when the user clicks a button (like "Add New Category")

Here is my code:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(300,200))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        button = wx.Button(self.panel,-1,"Button")

        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox.Add(button)

        add_btn = wx.Button(self.panel,-1,"Add")
        add_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add)

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(add_btn)

        main_vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_vbox.Add(self.vbox)
        main_vbox.Add(hbox)

        self.panel.SetSizer(main_vbox)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def add(self,event):
        self.vbox.Add((wx.Button(self.panel,-1,"Button")))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainWindow(None, -1, 'Add a Button')
    app.MainLoop()
```

My problem is, the button gets added on top of the previous button. I'm rather mystified by this, because if I delete the `event` argument of the `add()` function, and then call it in the `__init__` method, `self.add()`, it works fine. But that doesn't help me any because I need to add the widgets when the user clicks the button.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Call `self.panel.Layout()` after adding the button.  This function is called automatically when you resize a window with children (try it with your current code), but not when you add widgets to it.